# RTC and System clock not in sync

Tags: suse, clock

How to set the system clock sync with RTC (Hardware Clock / BIOS). I am writing a script that uses a system clock in order to start the system with alarm.

For this the sole requirement is to have a proper RTC clock. On my test system  (SLES 10 SP4), I use NTP Server to manage the system clock. But the RTC clock is always ahead.

So for example : currently the system clock shows  `14:00 26.05.2016` and the RTC shows `16:00` Hrs. I read the man pages of `hwclock` and it shows that following command

```
hwclock --systohc --localtime
```

would sync the RTC clock to system clock. Which it did.

But after a reboot/shutdown, when the system comes up again, the RTC is again messed up. So there is something more which controls the RTC when the system is rebooted.

Could someone point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What time zone is the system set to?  Try using `--utc` rather than `--localtime`.  Lastly, what does `hwclock` show after you run it with `--systohc`?

Comment: A Unix system's system clock should be set to UTC.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `hwclock` command to set the hardware clock.
From the man `hwclock page` :

```
 --set  Set the Hardware Clock to the time given by the --date option.
```

You can apply the current system time to the hw clock with :

```
hwclock -w
```

or even manually with :

```
hwclock --set --date "$(date)"
```

After you added details to your question, my answer is not enough though, so here are more details below.
You can check timezone with the `timedatectl status` command.
List timezones with `timedatectl list-timezones`.
You can set your timezone to UTC for example with `timedatectl set-timezone UTC`.
You will find more details about timezone settings [here](http://www.tecmint.com/set-time-timezone-and-synchronize-time-using-timedatectl-command/).

Comment: I tried above command but it did not set the time. pluto:~ # curr_da=$(date "+%d %m %Y %H:%M")
pluto:~ # echo $curr_da
26 05 2016 16:45
pluto:~ # hwclock --set --date "${curr_da}" 
date: invalid date `26 05 2016 16:45'
The date command issued by hwclock returned unexpected results.
The command was:
  date --date="26 05 2016 16:45" +seconds-into-epoch=%s
The response was:

No usable set-to time.  Cannot set clock.
pluto:~ #

Comment: thanx but timedatectl command not found.

Comment: ok `hwclock -w` or my corrected example should work. can you install `timedatectl` ?

Comment: Since my Installation Timezone is CEST . It makes sense that system clock always goes +2Hrs ahead than RTC (which i manually set to current time).

So e.g. here the current time is = 11:00 which I set in BIOS as well. And then booted the system and it shows now : 13:00

But then how do I set both these clocks show same time? I dont think I should change the timezone completely as it is correctly set to Europe.

Answer (score 2):

On `systemd` based systems running `timedatectl` will give a warning if your clocks are not set optimally:

```
Warning: The system is configured to read the RTC time in the local time zone.
         This mode can not be fully supported. It will create various problems
         with time zone changes and daylight saving time adjustments. The RTC
         time is never updated, it relies on external facilities to maintain it.
```

This can be fixed with:

`timedatectl set-local-rtc 0`

Comment: One should also note that this will overwrite the RTC (the BIOS time) with the current system time (from Linux to BIOS). If the BIOS is correct and you want your Linux machine to understand it, and align its clock with the BIOS, keeping in consideration the time-zone, use also the --adjust-system-clock  flag, which will update the system time (Linux time) to the BIOS time adding the delta from the time zone. If the time zone is not set one can use "timedatectl set-timezone <time-zone>" first. This is particularly important for dual boot amchines were Windows assumes the RTC is UTC.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and solved it, with the command you quoted: `hwclock --systohc --localtime`, just adding it at system startup, using crontab.

To do this, add command to a file (I used RTC adjust.sh)

[image]

After that, open terminal and run `chmod 755` on path to your script, as this example:

```
chmod 755 /home/andavas/Scripts/RTC adjust.sh
```

Then edit your crontab file for editing:

```
crontab -e
```

(If you never run this, you must choose an editor for this task. I recommend `nano`)

At the end of the file, insert path to script, preceded by `@reboot`:

[image]

Lastly, save and reboot your system.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. To make the post as useful as possible to readers, would you mind summarizing the steps needed for including the command to the system startup, as well as what specific kind of system the steps apply to (SystemV, Upstart, systemd, ...)?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a virtual machine? Or a physical system on blade hardware?

Some manufacturers' blade hardware has an option to sync the hardware clocks of each blade to the clock of the management processor of the blade enclosure. At least on (some models of) Fujitsu's blade hardware, this sync option was enabled by default. To turn it off, you had to access the BIOS settings of the blade.

Virtual machines usually sync their virtual hardware clock according to the clock of the physical host system at VM initialization time, since a virtual machine cannot have a real physical hardware clock. If your hosting provider has primarily Windows systems, the syncing may have been configured to use local time rather than UTC.

---

And there is one gotcha that can affect both physical and virtual systems, particularly if running enterprise Linux distributions:

Before the `hwclock` tool and the convention to indicate the RTC being set up to either UTC or local time in `/etc/adjtime` existed, there were several distribution-specific methods to store this setting. For backwards compatibility, these methods may still exist. And enterprise distributions are especially keen on backwards compatibility.

This can cause problems when the UTC/local setting in `/etc/adjtime` is in conflict with the corresponding legacy setting in `/etc/sysconfig/clock`, `/etc/default/rcS` or similar: the distribution's initramfs may respect the legacy method while the the `hwclock` command run interactively by the sysadmin follows `/etc/adjtime` unless overridden - and will automatically store the new setting to `/etc/adjtime` **only** if the `--utc` or `--local` options are used.

To fix it:

- make sure that `/etc/adjtime` and any legacy settings in `/etc/sysconfig/clock`, `/etc/default/rcS` or similar are in agreement as to whether the hardware clock runs in UTC or local time, to avoid different tools making different interpretations
- after that, update your initramfs file, to make sure that early boot processes use the same settings as the rest of the system.

If you don't do this, you may get a system whose clock gets shifted by exactly the amount of the current UTC offset at each boot.

If you need to minimize the risk of this happening again, you might investigate if your distribution supports setting the legacy UTC/localtime configuration to "neutral" somehow, so that `/etc/adjtime` will be the only source of truth in this matter. Because the startup scripts will normally access the hardware clock only through `hwclock`, the legacy configuration might in fact be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you system is set up. Normally Unix expects the RTC to be in GMT/UTC, and the system knows its offset/timezone... But this is incompatible with old Windows systems that expect the RTC to be in local time and this causes problems in multi-boot systems. So there is  a setting in /etc/default/rcS to tell if your system uses a RTC in GMT or local time (you likely want the latter, which is not the default):

```
# assume that the BIOS clock is set to UTC time (recommended)
UTC=yes
```

Comment: # hwclock --debug
hwclock from util-linux-2.12r
Using /dev/rtc interface to clock.
Last drift adjustment done at 1464276196 seconds after 1969
Last calibration done at 1464276196 seconds after 1969
Hardware clock is on local time
Assuming hardware clock is kept in local time.
Waiting for clock tick...
...got clock tick
Time read from Hardware Clock: 2016/05/26 17:49:55
Hw clock time : 2016/05/26 17:49:55 = 1464277795 seconds since 1969
Thu May 26 17:49:55 2016  -0.000185 seconds